Steinitz Isomorphism Theorem for Non-Dedekind domains
Fix a Dedekind domain $R$ and fractional ideals $I, J$. It's a classical result by Steinitz that $I\oplus J \cong R \oplus IJ$ as $R$-modules.
Question Does this still hold for non-Dedekind 1-dimensional Noetherian domains, esp. non-maximal orders in number fields? Does it hold when assuming that $I,J$ are invertible?
I've seen this stated without proof and can't seem to find good literature on the topic. Literature recommendations on extending basic results on Dedekind domains to arbitrary orders in number fields are welcome.
Once one reduces to $I,J$ integral and $I+J=R$, the result is completely general (see e.g. Let $R$ be a ring. Prove $I \oplus J \cong R \oplus IJ$ as $R$-modules.). However, I can't find a reduction to this case generalized beyond Dedekind domains.

It holds more generally when $I$ and $J$ are coprime, see here.

Yes, that's true, but I can't make that assumption in my case, and don't see how the reduction to this special case can be generalized beyond Dedekind domains (the proof I've seen uses weak approximation).
